# Entity Framework 6 и большие объемы данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework, оптимизация

Есть проект на C# с EF6.
Перегрузка данных. 
На данный момент данных порядка 120к записей 
И очень большой вопрос стал с производительностью. 
С каждой 1000 обработанных записей - скорость обработки падает. И падает очень существенно. 
И в итоге... обработка всех 120к записей затягивается на 2-3 суток.
Пробовал `Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled=false;`

Результат не особо отличается. 
Сохранение контекста делается практически после каждой логической цепочки.

Подскажите как оптимизировать работу?

Comment: Покажите код для начала, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Контекст в EF это (в том числе) реализация Unit of Work. Он не должен быть долгоживущим. Время жизни контекста - одна бизнес-операция.

Делать один контекст на приложение, или держать контекст живым несколько часов - заведомо плохая идея.

Не держите контекст живым так долго. Создавайте новый контекст на каждую "логическую цепочку".

Если у вас контекст живет долго только ради какого-то верхнего `foreach (var obj in context.Objects)` - перепишите на цикл по коллекции id объектов в памяти. Или на цикл, который в начале итерации выбирает первую необработанную записью. На что угодно, но так, чтобы сверху не было общего `using (var context = new)`

Answer (score 0):

Скажем так - 120 тысяч записей - это никакие не "большие объемы данных". Я бы даже сказал, что это совсем небольшие объемы. Если каждая из ваших строк не имеет каких-нибудь умопомрачительных объемов, то это вообще должно быть пустяком. Так как вы не предоставляете каких-то конкретных данных и не описываете ни вашу БД, ни модели, сказать что-то определенное тут трудно. Хотя, конечно, 2-3 дня для такого небольшого количества записей - это какой-то адский трэш, что не должно быть характерно даже для ORM, в том числе и Entity. Почти наверняка уверен, что вы как-то ошибочно работаете с Entity и/или выполняете некую зубодробительную логику на не менее зубодробительных данных - в нормальных условиях Entity не станет обрабатывать 120 тысяч записей так долго.

Однако если планируете переходить на по-настоящему большие данные (или даже на средние объемы), то имеет смысл отказаться от Entity в пользу обычyого ADO.NET

Comment: Если данные находятся в тормозной сети то всякое может быть ;-)

Comment: @cpp_user ну и это, конечно, и много других причин можно выдумать, но тут имеет смысл исходить из принципа бритвы Оккама