# Использование разных источников данных singleton

Tags: c#, база-данных, singleton

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с такой проблемой - необходимо реализовать singleton с возможностью работы с разными бд (ну допустим мои коннекшены лежат в классе Setting). Через DataManager(singleton) работаю с репозиториями, которые унаследованы от BaseRepository

```
public sealed class DataManager
    {
        public FabricRepository Fabric { get; set; }
        public FabricProductRepository FabricProduct { get; set; }
        public FittingRepository Fitting { get; set; }
        public FittingProductRepository FittingProduct { get; set; }
        public OrderRepository Order { get; set; }
        public ProductOrderRepository ProductOrder { get; set; }
        public ProductRepository Product { get; set; }
        public StockFabricRepository StockFabric { get; set; }
        public StockFittingRepository StockFitting { get; set; }
        public UserRepository User { get; set; }

        private DataManager()
        {
            Fabric = new FabricRepository();
            FabricProduct = new FabricProductRepository();
            Fitting = new FittingRepository();
            FittingProduct = new FittingProductRepository();
            Order = new OrderRepository();
            ProductOrder = new ProductOrderRepository();
            Product = new ProductRepository();
            StockFabric = new StockFabricRepository();
            StockFitting = new StockFittingRepository();
            User = new UserRepository();
        }

        static DataManager _active = null;
        static object _syncRoot = new object();

        public static DataManager Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_active == null)
                    lock (_syncRoot)
                        if (_active == null)
                            _active = new DataManager();

                return _active;
            }
        }
    }



abstract public class BaseRepository<T>
        where T : class, new()
    {
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        private List<T> List = new List<T>();

        public BaseRepository()
        {
            this.TableName = typeof(T).Name;
        }

        public virtual ICollection<T> GetList()
        {
            FillList();
            return List;
        }
```

Вот например как я добавляю данные в базу: DataManager.Instance.User.Add(user);
Я так полагаю необходимо в синглтон классе создать поле SqlConnection?

Comment: ни в коем случае

Comment: @Igor или передавать в конструктор BaseRepository строку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я так полагаю необходимо в синглтон классе создать поле SqlConnection?

**Ответ:**

Не стоит создавать соединение в Singlton классе так как таким образом вы нарущите изоляцию репозиториев друг от друга. Вы можете создавать соеденение непосредственно в каждом репозитории и таком образом реализовать работу с каким угодно количеством БД. Можно например строку подключения передавать в конструктор.

Хорошим тоном будет использование ORM и моделей. После чего создаете один контекст на один репозиторий.

**UPD**

Как справедливо заметил **PashaPash** не стоит использовать один контекст постоянно ровно как и один экземпляр **SqlConnection**. В целях избежания проблем стоит создавать новый **SqlConnection** или **DbContext** на каждый запрос. И обязательно не забывать оборачивать его в **using**.

Также приведу полезные ссылки от **PashaPash**:

[Конкретный пример последствий долгоживущего контекста](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438471)

[Развернутый ответ на эту же тему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508152/177221)

**Дополнительно:**

Я бы посоветовал вам для начала прочитать про ORM (например Entity Framework). После чего почить [вот эту занимательную статейку](https://oxozle.com/2015/01/26/ispol-zovanie-patterna-repository-v-entityframework-generic-repository) про работу с репозиториями.

Формулировка ORM из википедии:

> ORM (англ. Object-Relational Mapping, рус. объектно-реляционное
>   отображение, или преобразование) — технология программирования,
>   которая связывает базы данных с концепциями объектно-ориентированных
>   языков программирования, создавая «виртуальную объектную базу данных».
>   Существуют как проприетарные, так и свободные реализации этой
>   технологии.

Формулировка Entity Framework из википедии:

> ADO.NET Entity Framework (EF) — объектно-ориентированная технология
>   доступа к данным, является object-relational mapping (ORM) решением
>   для .NET Framework от Microsoft. Предоставляет возможность
>   взаимодействия с объектами как посредством LINQ в виде LINQ to
>   Entities, так и с использованием Entity SQL. Для облегчения построения
>   web-решений используется как ADO.NET Data Services (Astoria), так и
>   связка из Windows Communication Foundation и Windows Presentation
>   Foundation, позволяющая строить многоуровневые приложения, реализуя
>   один из шаблонов проектирования MVC, MVP или MVVM.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/228687)

Comment: @alexander barakin, исправил ответ.

Comment: @PashaPash♦ , так. Стоп. А где это вы прочитали что там написано что создается соеденение одно и на всегда? Там лишь написано что необходимо создовать соеденение в репозитории. Написанно что не стоит создавать его в синглтоне. Также даны все полезные ссылки. А контекст сам умеет управлять пулом соеденений.

Comment: @PashaPash♦ , ну и на по следок. А как вы думаете, каким образом работает пул соединений? Неужели там все время создаются новые? А разве пул соединений это не переиспользование уже созданных? И разве можно сказать в такой ситуации что это короткоживущий объект? Вы сейчас влепили минус и написали гневный комментарий никак не обосновывая свою претензию.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71828/discussion-between-pashapash-and--).